# Is the Main method must needed in a Java program?

Tags: java

Is the main method needed to write a java program?

This is my code:

```
package example;

public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {

    }

    public String getHelloWorld() {

        return "Hello From Java!";
    }
}
```

It shows an error at compilation:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: This looks like a runtime error, not a compilation error.

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main method is not needed in java programs.  As others have pointed out, web applications do not use the main method.

It is not even needed in standalone applications.  Consider

```
class JavaAppWithoutMain
{
    static
    {
    System . out . println ( "Hello World!" ) ;
    }
}
```

I compiled it and ran and obtained the following result:

```
Hello World!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

For standalone applications you must either have

1. a main method or
2. a static initializer.

Main is preferred.

Comment: From what I understand modern java no longer allows this abuse of the static initializer.

Comment: @emory why is the main method preferred? Because static initializers aren't meant for this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Abdul I suspect yes.

Comment: @emory i think you should also mention that static initializer was only allowed in java version 1.6 or before, now its not allowed (you must have a main method)

Comment: @Matuagkeetarp It is not important enough for me to verify, but I image one could specify the JRE version which would allow one to continue using the static initializer (but then one would not be able to use anything introduced after 1.6).  But then as now, there is no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 10):

The `main` method is the default entry point for a programme. If you don't define one, and then try to execute the jar produced, this is what you'll see. If you're not trying to produce a programme that needs launching independently, you won't need it - for example, a jar referenced by other programmes, or a website.

Answer (score 7):

Without a [`main` method you application will have no entry point](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html).  Yes, it is required for any executable program.

Answer (score 7):

If you try to execute a Java class, the JVM will look for a `main` method to invoke it. From the [**CHAPTER 12 Execution**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html) of the Java Language Specification:

> A Java virtual machine starts up by loading a specified class and then invoking the method `main` in this specified class. Section [§12.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44444)  outlines the loading, linking, and initialization steps involved in executing `main`, as an introduction to the concepts in this chapter. Further sections specify the details of loading [(§12.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44459), linking [(§12.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44487), and initialization [(§12.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44557).

Not all classes need a `main`, only the one that serve as "entry point" for execution.

Comment: "Not all classes need a main, only the one that serve as "entry point" for execution." +1 For mentioning, this is something beginners often get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not needed for e.g. web applications. They do not use a `main()` method, but if you are testing or running a stand-alone application, to know what output you are expecting, you might require a `main()` method.

Comment: However, web applications typically specify another method as entry-point in Java EE.

Answer (score 2):

Standalone applications require main, because it is entry-point. How will JVM know where to start program?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're getting this error message is because you're attempting to run a class using java (java.exe on Windows) and it's expecting to find a main() method.

This method isn't required as such but it can form an entry point where an application is initiated. You can rewrite your class as follows to achieve the result you were seeking:

```
package example;
public class HelloWorld {

 // Running a class using java invokes this method
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();

  System.out.println( hw.getHelloWorld() );
 }

 public HelloWorld() { 
 }

 public String getHelloWorld() {
  return "Hello From Java!";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your java application or program (not every single class) needs atleast one main method to run it. And the one you have got is not a compilation error but a run time error.

Answer (score 0):

"When you save program with the name same as the class name which contain main() method, then at the time of execution the JVM will create a object of that class and with that object JVM will call the main() metod as object.main().

So if main()  method is missing( static initializer is also missing ) then it will throw an exception."

For web application same explanation as above.

ref: [Java Understanding Java main method on logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922749/java-understanding-java-main-method-on-logic)