# Does all java programs start with main?

Tags: java

1. Web servers like : Apache Tomcat.
2. App servers like : Weblogic.
3. EJB containers.
4. Android java container.
   5> all the other java implementations?

Comment: All Java programs must start with a main method. Sometimes the method is visible to the programmer, and sometimes (such as with applets), it's not.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "Java programs". Applets for example starts with `init`.

Comment: @Pshemo: but that ignores the fact that there is a main method required somewhere, in this situation in the applet launching code, away from programmer's eyes, but regardless, the main *must* be there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels your right. To start JVM we ned to use some variant of `java SomeClass` command which searches for `main` method in that class.

Answer (score 1):

Usually yes.
But no, it is not required ... as eloquently pointed out by this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897323/1481262

Also, while instrumenting the code of applications (using the `java.lang.instrument` package), the execution starts with the `premain` method before the `main` is executed. - [1] [2].

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html
[2] http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you start a java program, you specify the class to use, and it's static `main` method is invoked with the command line arguments.

Comment: What about class is implementing threads then main functions is not needed. Everything goes in run method

Comment: @ShivamTiwari: but what code gets *started* in the JVM? There must be a main to get things started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all java programs begin with main, though it's not necessary for each class to have it's individual main function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all programs should start with `main` , It is something like contract between JDK and  JRE.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE [always starts from a `main()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2). However, it is possible to start up a JRE and use it to run several independent *programs*. For example, a browser will often run all its applets [in the same JRE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can write a custom launcher instead of java.exe, like here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17352/JVM-Launcher. Take a look at how they invoke `main`:

```
//Find the class
jclass    jcJclass = psJNIEnv->FindClass(mainClassName);

//Find the main method id
jmethodID jmMainMethod = 
    psJNIEnv-> GetStaticMethodID(jcJclass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

//Call the main method.
psJNIEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcJclass, jmMainMethod, joApplicationArgs);
```

that is, it could be any method